# In WooCommerce product options edit page display a custom field before the SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, inventory

So I've got the following function to add a barcode field in the Product Inventory tab. However this field is being added after all the other content, and I would like to have this before the SKU code.

```
function add_barcode(){
    global $woocommerce,$post;
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'          => '_barcode',
            'label'       => __('Barcode','woocommerce'),
            'placeholder' => 'Scan Barcode',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
            'description' => __('Scan barcode.','woocommerce')
        ));
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data','add_barcode');
```

Is there anyway to place the function/field before the SKU aka before the actual hook, like something in terms of woocommerce_before_product_options_inventory_product_data?

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **IS NOT POSSIBLE TO PLACE ANY CUSTOM FIELD BEFORE THE SKU** 
>  
>   You can take a look to [**`html-product-data-inventory.php`** source code file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-product-data-inventory.php) which displays product inventory fields.

**But you can display your 'Barcode' custom field just after the SKU field** *(for example)*

For that you have to hook your custom function in **`woocommerce_product_options_sku`** action hook instead. There is also some missing things in your code to display a saved value.

And finally you need another function to save that value when product is saved or updated.

Here is that complete code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku','add_barcode_custom_field' );
function add_barcode_custom_field(){
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_barcode',
        'label'       => __('Barcode','woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => 'Scan Barcode',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __('Scan barcode.','woocommerce')
    ) ); 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_barcode_custom_field', 10, 1 );
function save_barcode_custom_field( $post_id ){
    if( isset($_POST['_barcode']) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_barcode', esc_attr( $_POST['_barcode'] ) );
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce version 2.6+ and 3.0+