# Using ACF plugin to add barcode information to WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, json, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am using ACF to add barcode information to the WooCommerce product page. It has to be with the terms here:

Has to follow the one here: https://support.convictional.com/woocommerce/adding-barcode-values-in-woo-commerce#adding_barcode_values_in_woo_commerce
with terms as they asked.

```json
[{ "id": 1, 
   "key": "barcode",
   "value": "12345678912" 
}, 
{ 
   "id": 2, 
   "key": "barcode_type", 
   "value": "upc" 
}]
```

Could any experts here let me know how and where to set it up please?

I did set up test area in the ACF with `barcode` and `barcode_type` but showing differently on the page.

Answer (score 1):

ACF is not convenient for this purpose as the real meta key will never be like `"barcode"` or `"barcode_type"`, but something like: `"field_648f2aaff9f4b"` as you can see in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899533/retrieving-related-data-with-wordpress-and-advanced-custom-fields/76900114#76900114) or in [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76456726/display-checkout-acf-advanced-custom-fields-and-save-the-value-in-woocommerce/76457676#76457676)…

Based on [In WooCommerce product options edit page display a custom field before the SKU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698813/in-woocommerce-product-options-edit-page-display-a-custom-field-before-the-sku/43699509#43699509) answer, you can easily add 2 custom fields in the product settings under Inventory section.

[image]

This way, you will have the correct meta keys to be recognized and used via REST API.

The code:

```php
// Utility function: Barcode type options
function get_options_barcode_type() {
    return array(
        'upc'       => __('UPC'),
        'gtin'      => __('GTIN'),
        'isbn'      => __('ISBN'),
    );
}


// Admin: Add custom fields to product inventory section
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'add_product_barcode_fields' );
function add_product_barcode_fields(){

    echo '<div class="class="barcode-options options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'          => 'barcode_type',
        'label'       => __('Barcode type', 'woocommerce' ),
        'options'     => get_options_barcode_type(),
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => 'barcode',
        'label'       => __('Barcode', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter the barcode', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Admin: Save custom field values
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_product_barcode_field_values', 10, 1 );
function save_product_barcode_field_values( $product ){
    if( isset($_POST['barcode_type']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( 'barcode_type', esc_attr($_POST['barcode_type']) );
    }

    if( isset($_POST['barcode']) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( 'barcode', sanitize_text_field($_POST['barcode']) );
    }
}
```

To display the barcode in single product pages in the meta section *(near the* SKU):

[image]

```php
// Display The Barcode on product single page in meta section (with the SKU)
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_start', 'display_single_product_meta_barcode' );
function display_single_product_meta_barcode() {
    global $product; 

    if( $barcode = $product->get_meta('barcode') ) {
        $barcode_options = get_options_barcode_type();
        $barcode_type    = $product->get_meta('barcode_type');
        printf('<span class="barcode_wrapper">%s: <span class="barcode">%s</span></span>', 
            $barcode_type ? $barcode_options[$barcode_type]: reset($barcode_options), $barcode );    
    }              
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

[Other related threads around GTIN and barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754%20gtin)